# MediaPlayer doesn't start when CountDownTimer is finished

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I have a `CountDownTimer` like this:

```
cuentaAtras = new CountDownTimer(mili, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                long seconds = millisUntilFinished / 1000;


                if (seconds  <= TIEMPO3){

                    if (tic1.isPlaying()){
                        tic1.stop();
                        tic2.start();
                    }

                } else if (seconds <= TIEMPO && seconds > TIEMPO2 + 10){
                    tic1.start();
                }
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                if (tic2.isPlaying())
                {
                    tic2.stop();
                }
                ticExp.start();

                tic1.reset();
                tic2.reset();
                ticExp.reset();

            }
        }.start();
```

Variables `tic1`, `tic2` y `ticExp` type is **`MediaPlayer`** :

```
 tic1 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.tic1);
 tic1.setLooping(true);
 tic2 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.tic3);
 tic2.setLooping(true);
 ticExp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.exp);
```

When I execute `onFinish` method, the MediaPlayer `ticExp` should be played, but this doesn't occur.

I tested write `ticExp.start()` in method *`onTick`* and this works, so the file is not corrupted or something like this.
I don't have idea why in *`onTick`* method works, but in *`onFinish`* no.
(But the others sentences of code in `onFinish` are executed without problems)

Definitively, I want that `ticExp` will be played in `onFinish` method.

Sorry for my English. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing `ticExp.reset();` after `ticExp.start();` in `onFinish()`, That means you are actually starting and also resetting(making it idle). Just remove `ticExp.reset();` in `onFinish()`.

For the Complete State of `MediaPlayer`, you can [refer this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)

And one more thing, Your else condition in `onTick` method will never execute.

Comment: Thank you so much! What a fail. A lot of hours in front of PC :( And my else condition is executed, because `TIEMPO3` is `10` and `seconds` start on `30`.

Comment: Sorry, you have 2 condition one is **seconds <= TIEMPO** and **seconds > TIEMPO2 + 10** and you have **&&** operator for both, so both should satisfy the condition If we take your example **30 <= 10 && 30 > 20** this will fail so it will not go inside your loop.